# Windows 8 Live Tile Background Agent Using C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, live-tile

I am trying to update a live tile every so often on Windows 8 and need to do this even if the app itself isn't running. None of the notification options listed on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761484.aspx) are suitable, I want to poll system information like CPU temp etc which doesn't suit the styles of notifications listed.

I've looked elsewhere on StackOverflow and seen similar questions but for Windows Phone 7 [using background workers](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/25/31-days-of-mango-day-25-background-agents/). Using a background worker seems like the right answer for me as well. However, tutorials like the previous one focus on Windows Phone 7 where things are a bit different, the Windows Store templates in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate don't have C# templates for Scheduled Task Agents for example.

So my question is how can we set up background workers for Windows 8 apps to preform live tile updates when the application itself isn't running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can read about Background Tasks [here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/12/31-days-of-windows-8-day-12-background-tasks); read about TimeTrigger [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977059), and in method OnCompleted at operation background task, we can set LiveTile

```
    void OnCompleted(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    { 
      var tile = CreateNotification(String.Format(@"<tile>
      <visual>
        <binding template=""TileSquareText04"">
          <text id=""1"">{0}</text>
          <text id=""2""></text>
        </binding> 
        <binding template=""TileSquareText02"">
          <text id=""1"">{0}</text>
          <text id=""2""></text>
        </binding>  
      </visual>
    </tile>", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")));
     TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tile);
     }
    private TileNotification CreateNotification(string xml)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
        return new TileNotification(xmlDocument);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the whitepaper: [Introduction to Background Tasks](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411); between that and what you've already learned and researched about tiles, you should be able to pull something together.