# How can I monitor a folder for changes in the background of a Windows App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Windows 8 App that will primarily run in the background.  This app will be specific to computers (i.e. no tablets or phones, in case that makes a difference).  It needs to be able to watch a specified folder while it is running in the background and be notified when there is a change in that folder.  Because it is a Windows Store App I cannot use a `FileSystemWatcher`, which would be perfect in my situation.  Also, I cannot use a timer to watch the folder because these changes will be occurring every 10-15 seconds and the timer does not support times shorter than 15 minutes.  What other options do I have?

Comment: You could have it run a background program that does the checking and returns whenever there is a change. That would get around the 15 minute limitation.

Comment: @JABFreeware So I would have to write another program that would watch the folder, package it into an executable, add the executable to my app, make my app run it, then tell my app to listen for messages from the executable?

Comment: One solution would be to not put your application in a store that purposefully prevents you from doing what you want to do.

Comment: @Garrett exactly to the question posted by garrett!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I must say that I absolutely despise Windows, mainly because of stupid stuff like this, however I currently have no other way of distributing this app and I need to get it out there

Comment: @Garrett Would my solution work for you?

Comment: @JABFreeware Well I'm not entirely sure how to do pretty much any of that, but I suppose if I could get it working then it is an option.  However, it is far from ideal.

Comment: @Garrett Well WN RT dev is less than ideal anyway

Comment: @JABFreeware I agree, but as I said I have no other options for distribution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21910/discussion-between-jabfreeware-and-garrett)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use a timer that fires every 15 seconds or so, the only thing I can recommend is running a simple loop, which before the loop it checks the system time from the system clock, and then with each loop it checks difference between current system clock and the originally stored value. When you get to 15 seconds the loop stops and starts the code that checks the folder. If the code in the loop is simple and makes use of a `Sleep` call it shouldn't take hardly any system resources.

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Busy waiting? At the very least suggest that he put some sort of `Sleep` call in the loop, if that's allowed that is... otherwise that's going to kill the CPU, and take the battery down with it! An empty loop does **not** use "hardly any system resources". It keeps the processor (or at least one core) running at 100% capacity constantly.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I believe he assumed that I would put a `Sleep` equivalent.  I know that it would kill the CPU otherwise.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen  yes I did assume that. I'll edit my answer just to clarify

Comment: @JABFreeware please don't think I have forgotten your answer, I'm just having difficulty getting it to to work

Comment: @JABFreeware Everything seems to be working, I just need a way to make the task start immediately.

Comment: Don't forget to run it in a separate thread and also kill the loop when you close the applicaiton

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Windows Apps Background tasks?  There's a question here:  [Windows 8 Live Tile Background Agent Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549854/windows-8-live-tile-background-agent-using-c-sharp)